# Create new dictionaries based on names of keys of another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `"A"`:

```py
A = {
    "Industry1": 1,
    "Industry2": 1,
    "Industry3": 1,
    "Customer1": 1,
    "Customer2": 1,
    "LocalShop1": 1,
    "LocalShop2": 1,
}
```

I want to group by key names and create new dictionaries for each "category", the names should be generated automatically.

##### Expected Output:

```
Industry = {
    "Industry1": 1,
    "Industry2": 1,
    "Industry3": 1,
}
Customer = {
    "Customer1": 1,
    "Customer2": 1,
}
LocalShop = {
    "LocalShop1": 1,
    "LolcalShop2": 1,
}
```

Can you guys give me a hint to achieve this output, please?

Comment: FWIW, the need to do a weird grouping like this means that at some step before this you aren't using appropriate data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your keys are in `(KEYNAME)(NUM)`, you can do the following:

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

A = {
    "Industry1": 1,
    "Industry2": 1,
    "Industry3": 1,
    "Customer1": 1,
    "Customer2": 1,
    "LocalShop1": 1,
    "LocalShop2": 1,
}

key_pattern = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+")

result = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in A.items():
    key = key_pattern.search(k).group()
    result[key][k] = v

pprint(dict(result))
```

output:

```
{'Customer': {'Customer1': 1, 'Customer2': 1},
 'Industry': {'Industry1': 1, 'Industry2': 1, 'Industry3': 1},
 'LocalShop': {'LocalShop1': 1, 'LocalShop2': 1}}
```

I created a dictionary of dictionaries instead of having individual variables for each dictionary. Its easier to manage and it doesn't pollute the global namespace.

Basically you iterate through the key value pairs and with `r"[a-zA-Z]+"` pattern, you grab the part without number. This is what is gonna be used for the key in outer dictionary.

Comment: I'm getting an random error, sometimes I run the jupyter notebook cell and it pops up ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26352/3158636403.py in <module>
----> 1 result = defaultdict(dict)
      2 for k, v in customers_ms3.items():
      3     key = key_pattern.search(k).group()
      4     result[key][k] = v
      5 

TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Comment: @Hapzek I guess you shadowed some names in your previous cells. Do not use builtin names like `dict` or ... as variable names.

Comment: Oops, yes, I was using **dict** as a variable name , thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of this answer I've assumed that every key in the dictionary A has either the word "Industry", "Customer", or "Shop" in it. This allows us to detect what category each entry needs to be in by checking if each key contains a certain substring (i.e. "Industry"). If this assumption doesn't hold for your specific circumstances, you'll have to find a different way to write the if/elif statements in the solutions below that fits your situation better.

Here's one way to do it. You make a new dictionary for each category and check if "Industry", "Customer", or "Shop" is in each key.

```
industries = {}
customers = {}
shops = {}

for key, value in A.items():
    if "Industry" in key:
        industries[key] = value
    elif "Customer" in key:
        customers[key] = value
    elif "Shop" in key:
        shops[key] = value
```

Another, cleaner version would be where you have a nested dictionary that stores all of your categories, and each category would have its own dictionary inside the main one. This would help in the future if you needed to add more categories. You'd only have to add them in one place (in the dictionary definition) and the code would automatically adjust.

```
categories = {
    "Industry": {},
    "Customer": {},
    "Shop": {},
}

for key, value in A.items():
    for category_name, category_dict in categories.items():
        if category_name in key:
            category_dict[key] = value
```

If you can't detect the category from the string of an entry, then you may have to store that categorical information in the key or the value of each entry in `A`, so that you can detect the category when trying to filter everything.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP needs. They said "*the names should be generated automatically*". You defined dictionaries yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a key that only extracts the word without the number. I wouldn't recommend to make variables of them, this is not scalable if there are more than 3 keys... just put them in a new dictionary or in a list.

```
A = {'Industry1': 1,
 'Industry2': 1,
 'Industry3': 1,
 'Customer1': 1,
 'Customer2': 1,
 'LocalShop1': 1,
 'LocalShop2': 1}

grouped = [dict(val) for k, val in itertools.groupby(A.items(), lambda x: re.match('(.+)\d{1,}', x[0]).group(1))]
```

Output `grouped`:

```
[
    {'Industry1': 1, 'Industry2': 1, 'Industry3': 1}, 
    {'Customer1': 1, 'Customer2': 1}, 
    {'LocalShop1': 1, 'LocalShop2': 1}
]
```

If you are sure, that there are exactly 3 elements in that list and you really want them as variables, you can do it with tuple unpacking:

```
Industry, Customer, LocalShop = [dict(val) for k, val in itertools.groupby(A.items(), lambda x: re.match('(.+)\d{1,}', x[0]).group(1))]
```

I think I would save the results in a new dictionary with the grouped key as new key and the list as value:

```
grouped_dict = {k: dict(val) for k, val in itertools.groupby(A.items(), lambda x: re.match('(.+)\d{1,}', x[0]).group(1))}
```

Output `grouped_dict`:

```
{'Industry': {'Industry1': 1, 'Industry2': 1, 'Industry3': 1},
 'Customer': {'Customer1': 1, 'Customer2': 1},
 'LocalShop': {'LocalShop1': 1, 'LocalShop2': 1}}
```

Comment: If you use `.groupby()` you need to make sure that the keys in dictionary are in correct order or sort it if needed, otherwise that's not gonna work. Check this for example : `A = {"Industry1": 1, "Customer1": 1, "Industry2": 1}`.

Comment: @S.B True, you are right, one more argument why I wouldn't recommend (as said) unpacking them into variables. Imo `grouped_dict` suits the best. Same like you also suggested.